# Is there a design pattern for validation?

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns, decorator, chain-of-responsibility

Is there any adequate design pattern that should be used in order to do number of validations?

For example, let's say that I have an application containing a toolbar with icons, each representing a picture on my file system. I am dragging an icon on a document. Validations during the drag and drop operation could be:

1. check if the file exists in file system
2. check if the user has access rights to drag the icon
3. check that the document is open in order to drop the picture on it

and so on...

I thought of using the Chain of Responsibility or Decorator patterns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you're after, or rather what I'd suggest, is [Continuation Passing Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). It's not so much a design pattern as a way of writing code where validation would be defined as a pipeline of methods that an object would go through. This pipeline would use an accumulator to collect all the validation problems encountered by the code.